# How to define column spacing on a bootstrap div?

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I've declared three div elements on a page and want to re-position the last div element so that it is one character closer to the second div on the same line.

What I have tried is editing the col values on the third div to be lower values, which I believed would push the div closer to the second div:

```
class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-1"
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect on the position of the third column.

**Question:**

How can I re-position the 3rd div element to move in closer to the 2nd div "Course Code:"?

I also tried increasing the col values of the 3rd div which puts the text onto a new line. Which is not the required positioning:

```
class="col-xs-7 col-sm-7 col-md-6 nwrp"
```

The three div controls as defined as follows in my asp page:

```
                        <div class="row mrgn">
                            <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-5"><h5><strong>Course Name:</strong></h5></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><h5><strong>Course Code:</strong></h5></div>
                            <div runat="server" id="OfferStatusTitle"  class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 nwrp"><h5><strong>Offer Status:</strong></h5></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-3"></div>
                        </div>
```

And this is what the three columns look like at present:

[image: div render on page]

Comment: Bootstrap divides a row by 12. in your case you are exceeding the 12 columns on sm/xs or not reach it in medium devices. if you want last section closer then do something like 6 4 2. or use this online tool : http://www.layoutit.com/build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every column in bootstrap have 15px padding on left and right. You can remove that to make content look more close on left side.
And you can't have more than 12 column in same row.

And if you want you can make more precise add new div inside second div and in that div you will have 12 columns so you can specify more precisely.

```
 <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-5"><h5><strong>Course Name:</strong></h5></div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-2 ">
     <div class='row'>
          <div class='col-xs-6 nwrp'>
               <h5><strong>Course Code:</strong></h5>
          </div>
          <div runat="server" id="OfferStatusTitle"  class="col-xs-6 nwrp"><h5><strong>Offer Status:</strong></h5>
          </div>
     </div>  
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-3"></div>
```

It is true that you can have 12 column in one row but inside any div tag you can have another 12 columns. And use row class for first inner class else there will be 30px padding on left and right for first and last div tag respectively.

row has -15px margin on left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to increase the third column width means split the column values as below:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 ">
  <div class="col-md-3">Course Name:</div>
  <div class="col-md-2">Course Code:</div>
  <div class="col-md-7">Offer Status:</div></div>
</div>
```

[Refer this link you can find more option.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)

Comment: Rememer to wrap the inner columns in another `row`

Comment: I edited my question above, there is an a fourth div. How can I make the same edit taking that into account?